# What is a top-level target when building `//...` in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

According to the [Bazel glossary](https://bazel.build/reference/glossary#top-level-target):

> A build target is top-level if it’s requested on the Bazel command
> line. For example, if //:foo depends on //:bar, and bazel build //:foo
> is called, then for this build, //:foo is top-level, and //:bar isn’t
> top-level, although both targets will need to be built. An important
> difference between top-level and non-top-level targets is that command
> flags set on the Bazel command line (or via .bazelrc) will set the
> configuration for top-level targets, but might be modified by a
> transition for non-top-level targets.

However, if the user runs `bazel build //...` then are all targets considered top-level or none?

This is relevant to the remote caching option [`--remote_download_outputs`](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--remote_download_outputs)

Answer (score 2):

What is returned by the expansion of the `*` and `...` wildcards is considered top-level.

Comment: To make this more concrete, this is described as Step 6 in the command execution process described here: https://bazel.build/contribute/codebase#command-process -- `The set of target patterns on the command line is parsed and wildcards like //pkg:all and //pkg/... are resolved. This is implemented in AnalysisPhaseRunner.evaluateTargetPatterns() and reified in Skyframe as TargetPatternPhaseValue.`